# "Package synaptic is not available" in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: synaptic

I can't install synaptic package manager in Ubuntu 16.04.
I do this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

And I see

```
Package synaptic is not available, but is referred to by another package. 
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only 
available from another source 
E: Package 'synaptic' has no installation candidate
```

What can I do?

The output of `sudo apt update` command:

```
Hit:1 http://archive.canonical.com xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                      
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

Comment: Are you running a LiveUSB? Are you connected to the internet?

Comment: i've downloaded ubuntu with liveUSB, but i dnt know how to download synaptic via LiveUSB...

Comment: Did you install the system, or just run it from Live USB?

Comment: system is installed on computer.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the output of `sudo apt update` command.

Comment: here u are,please.

Answer (score 3):

Go to System Settings -> Software and Updates and check the "universe" repository.

You can also enable "multiverse" and "restricted" too.

Then the package will get installed after `sudo apt update`.

Normally these repositories are enabled by default in installed systems, but are disabled in Live systems. In your case the repositries are not enabled for some reason.

Comment: ok, i do this, and what next? how now i can install synaptic, by typing sudo apt-get install synaptic ?

Comment: Next install `synaptic` by `sudo apt install synaptic`.

Comment: Did you install synaptic successfully? If yes, then please accept this answer by clicking the check sign at the left. Regarding Skype you can ask another question, or find a solution yourself. Tip: you will need to enable "Canonical Partners" repository on "Other Software" tab.

Comment: @KateBuchynska I just answered about Skype.